# Call to undefined method Yii::import()

Tags: php, yii2

Getting Error Call to undefined method Yii::import() 
As i am trying to access my  Yii controllers action i am getting this error please 
guide me who do i access and where i am going wrong now 
my code is

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use app\models\LoginForm;
use app\models\ContactForm;
use app\controllers\SSPController;


class BrandController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    { 

     Yii::import('application.controllers.admin.SSPController');
     SSPController::getdata();

    }
}
```

my SSPController Class Code is Like from which i want to call method getdata()

```
 <?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use app\models\LoginForm;
use app\models\ContactForm;

class SSPController extends Controller
{


static function getdata(){

    $primaryKey = 'user_id';
    $table = 'gc_od_chat';
    $columns_names=$arrayName = array("user_email","user_username");
    $columns = array(
        array( 'db' => 'columns_names[0]', 'dt' => 'columns_names[0]', 'field' => 'columns_names[0]' ),
        array( 'db' => 'columns_names[1]',  'dt' => 'columns_names[1]', 'field' => 'columns_names[1]' ),
    );

    $sql_details = array(
        'user' =>"root",
        'pass' => "",
        'db'   => "octachat",
        'host' => "localhost"
    );

    echo json_encode(
    $this->simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, $joinQuery, $extraWhere )
    );



        }
            }
```

Comment: There is no Yii::import() in Yii 2. You are using old Yii 1 code.

Comment: so how i acess action of another controller methods in my controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Yii::import() in Yii 2 but there are many ways to achieve this.

For example:

- make BrandController extend SSPController so it can use SSPController's methods
- call `Yii::$app->runAction('controller/action', $params);` (in case of `action` methods)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Bizley

`code 
class BrandController extends SSPController
{
    public function actionIndex()
    { 
     

     $data=Yii::$app->runAction('SSPController/getdata',["id" => "sdfsdaf"]);
      return $this->render('index');


    

    }
}

`
after creating as u metion getting this error on my view page
**Page not found
The above error occurred while the Web server was processing your request.
 Please contact us if you think this is a server error. Thank you.**

Comment: You are not suppose to use both methods at the same time. You can just call `return static::getdata();` in `actionIndex()`

Comment: you mean like this 
`Code 
class BrandController extends SSPController
{
    public function actionIndex()
    { 
     

     $data=Yii::$app->runAction('SSPController/getdata',array("id" => "sdfsdaf"));
      return static::getdata();
    

    }
}`

Comment: You don't need `$data=Yii::$app->runAction('SSPController/getdata',array("id‌​" => "sdfsdaf"));` line

Comment: oh i got it you means i access the method of parent class simply in child class no other thing i got it thanks alot brother thank u soooooooooooooooooooooooooooo mch